# Delete duplicate rows where time difference < @Time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to delete duplicate rows from a table where the time difference between the rows are < ex. 2minutes and where the dates and empnum are the same. I also want to keep the first row of the duplicates.

```
table : clockdates
+-----+------------+--------------+------------+
| ID  |    date    |     time     |   empnum   |
+-----+------------+--------------+------------+
|  1  | 2021/04/01 |   08:00:00   |    emp1    |
|  2  | 2021/04/01 |   08:01:00   |    emp1    |
|  3  | 2021/04/01 |   10:00:00   |    emp1    |
|  4  | 2021/04/01 |   16:30:00   |    emp1    |
|  5  | 2021/04/01 |   16:32:00   |    emp1    |
|  6  | 2021/04/01 |   17:00:00   |    emp2    |
|  7  | 2021/04/01 |   17:03:00   |    emp2    |
+-----+------------+--------------+------------+
```

Expected Results:

```
table : clockdates
+-----+------------+--------------+------------+
| ID  |    date    |     time     |   empnum   |
+-----+------------+--------------+------------+
|  1  | 2021/04/01 |   08:00:00   |    emp1    |
|  3  | 2021/04/01 |   10:00:00   |    emp1    |
|  4  | 2021/04/01 |   16:30:00   |    emp1    |
|  6  | 2021/04/01 |   17:00:00   |    emp2    |
|  7  | 2021/04/01 |   17:03:00   |    emp2    |
+-----+------------+--------------+------------+
```

I have tried the following code but it will only delete the rows where the times are exactly the same (10:00:00 and 10:00:00). I don't know how to use the @DupTime. (@DupTime is the minutes)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DelDup]
    @fDate date
AS 
DECLARE @DupTime INT = (SELECT [DupTime] FROM [dbo].[ProgramOptions])
WITH CTE([empnum], 
    [date], 
    [time], 
    duplicatecount)
AS (SELECT [empnum], 
           [date], 
           [time], 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [empnum], 
                                          [date], 
                                          [time]
           ORDER BY ID) AS DuplicateCount
    FROM [dbo].[clockdates])
DELETE FROM CTE
WHERE ClockDate >= @fDate AND DuplicateCount > 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `lag` it is as simple as the following, if I have understood correctly!

```
with d as (
    select Id, case when DateDiff(minute,Lag(time) over(partition by date, empnum order by id) , time)<=2 then 1 else 0 end del
    from clockdates
)
delete from d where del=1
```

Comment: Wow! This is exactly what I needed and so simple. Thank you. I'll have to read up a bit about the lag().

Comment: @SupertimeDeveloper Great! `lag` and similar `window fuctions` were introduced in 2012 and make a great number of previously tedious operations simple.